# getOwnerActivity returns null in custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I write a custom dialog and try to get some data from its parent activity, but I always get **null** when I call **getOwnerActivity**, could anyone tell me why this happen? Why I can show the data in the DemoDialog while failed to show data from TestDialogActivity?

Many thanks in advance.

**DialogTestActivity**

```
public class DialogTestActivity extends Activity {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public List<String> getData(){
        data.add("one");
        data.add("two");
        data.add("three");
        return data;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        return new DemoDialog(this);
    }
}
```

**DemoDialog**

```
public class DemoDialog extends Dialog {
    Context context;

    public DemoDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        this.context = context;
        setTitle("Delete City");
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ((DialogTestActivity)getOwnerActivity()).getData());
//      ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, getData());
        list.setAdapter(aa);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    private List<String> getData(){
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("1");
        data.add("2");
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think about the situation, you will understand why. When you call `new DemoDialog(this)`, you execute all the code in the constructor. After that, you return it from `onCreateDialog` and Android does its magic. If you try to get owner from the constructor, Android hasn't hooked it yet, so you have no owner yet.

So you can do either of these:

```
public class DemoDialog extends Dialog {
    public DemoDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // chances of context not being an activity is very low, but better to check.
        Activity owner = (context instanceof Activity) ? (Activity)context : null;
        if (owner != null) {
            // owner activity is defined here
        }
    }

    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        // getOwnerActivity() should be defined here if called via showDialog(), so do the related init here
        Activity owner = getOwnerActivity();
        if (owner != null) {
            // owner activity defined here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the second method is preferred because

Comment: Note: I mean the onCreate() call of the Dialog. However, you may need to put it in onAttachedToWindow() if that fails, because Android may in fact defer its magic arbitrarily. That said, if you need to access the owner from the constructor, the owner is "context", so just use "context" :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Sajid. I tried to follow your suggestion but sitll got null, could you please share your code?

Comment: Added as an edit above. You have to check in onAttachToWindow() after all.

Comment: I'm receiving null no matter where I call the owner. Tested on Android 5.1 Lollipop on a Moto G3.

Answer (score 26):

I tried to use `getOwnerActivity()` method in all possible methods of my `custom Dialog`. It always returns null (Android 2.3). Then I checked its source code and the activity it returns is set only in `setOwnerActivity(Activity activity)` which is not called anywhere. So if you want `getOwnerActivity()` to return value different than null, you have to do this:

```
public MyCustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        setOwnerActivity((Activity) context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extends your custom dialog from **`AppCompatDialog`** and access to activity by this code:

```
public static Activity scanForActivity(Context context) {
    if (context == null)
        return null;
    else if (context instanceof Activity)
        return (Activity) context;
    else if (context instanceof ContextWrapper)
        return scanForActivity(((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This, below, worked for me.

```
private Activity activity;

public MyCustomDialog(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Then I use activity instead of getOwnerActivity().

Comment: This may cause a circular reference, Dialog <-> Activity?

Comment: This is a good alternative answer. I dont know what Manuel is talking about.